# How to create a .sfm file in Java?

Tags: java

I'm creating code for a linguistics research team and need to export the final result as a .sfm (standard format marking) file. In my research, I can only find creation of .txt files; is there a way to create other types of files in Java or would it be better to find a separate program to export it?

Comment: A file's extension may not determine its actual contents. You should look into what the contents of an `.sfm` file look like and then determine if it's easy enough to create yourself. Otherwise, you should find an existing program to create it.

Comment: @JacobG. I have a couple text files that I need to reformat and  align together in a specific way, which I believe I know how to do. The problem is I need the specific extension for the program I'm using